# React Routing always gives me same Component no matter what

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So I am making a super simple react app, and I am trying to use routing,
But this:

```
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
       <Route exact path="/404" component={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>
)
```

Does not work, at all.
My imports are good, too.

```js
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

yet every time I run it, no matter what URL I go to, it always gives me `{App}`.
Why is this?

---

The code is in app.js and I am importing it into index.js

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` you on? If you are using v6 you should provide element prop instead of component to the `Route`.

Comment: @shubham what do you mean

Comment: On `/` route where do you want to redirect to `<Login/>` component or `<App />` component?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using version 6.3.0 of `react-router-dom` you need to use `element` instead of `component`. And `exact` attribute is not supported in `react-router-dom`. By default it matches the exact route. To match any **not found** route use "*" in the route path.

Import `BrowserRouter` as it is:

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
const routing = (
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
       <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
)
```

[Migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5#upgrading-from-v5)

Answer (score 0):

I figured that you are using `react-router-dom` version 6.

You need to provide JSX element like `element={<App />}` instead of `component={App}`.

You need -

```js
const routing = (
<React.StrictMode>
  <Router>
      <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
       <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
  </Router>
</React.StrictMode>
)
```

Notice that I haven't used any of `exact` because react router v6 is able to smartly understand which route element needs to be matched and matches it correctly without using `exact`.

Read through this migration guide- https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/upgrading/v5

Comment: Thank you! However, this returns a white page. `const router = (
  <Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Login/>} />
  </Routes>
  </Router>
)`

Comment: Are there any errors in console?? See the return statement of your login component

Comment: the return of login is a compenent, and no, no errors

Comment: If there are no errors in `console` then your return value of `Login` must be an empty `div` like `html!` Try using simple `h1` instead of using a component inside of `Login`